# Glimpse installation MVC Multi tier application

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, glimpse

i trying to install the glimpse on Multi tier application which has MVC 5 as front end  and Web API is Middle tier.

```
VS 2013 professional edition and below 2 glimse nuget packages are installed glimse.ado
glimse.aspnet
glimse.core 
glimse.EF6 
glimse.MVC5
```

Below are the error Could not load file or assembly `'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: hi I have VS 2013 professional edition and below 2 glimse nuget packages are installed
glimse.ado
glimse.aspnet
glimse.core
glimse.EF6
glimse.MVC5Below are the error 

Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.